# Why is my variable considered local when it should be global?

Tags: python

I've got a variable, and it's being used in the condition of a while loop inside a function. I get an error upon running that function saying: local variable 'audioLength' referenced before assignment

```
song = input("Enter a song to play: ")
songFile = song + ".mp3"
mp3File = MP3(songFile)
audioLength = int(mp3File.info.length)

def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song + ".mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while audioLength != 0:
        audioLength -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

I'm not sure why it thinks `audioLength` is a local variable, and how can I fix this?

Comment: It is global, but you have to add the line "global audioLength" at the beginning of the function to access it.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that but now it's saying: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Label' and 'int'. As if audioLength is a type 'Label' not an int even though i've made it an into outside the function

Comment: @Caleb: You only have to declare it as `global` in a function if its value is going to be changed there—the case here—although it doesn't hurt do so even when it's not required because having it will make what's going on a little more explicit.

Comment: It is being changed inside this function...

Comment: @Caleb: I know. I was correcting your earlier comment about having to do it as though it was always required.

Comment: Ibrahim: It sounds like you may have a name conflict if you're now getting errors like that (about `Label`). Ask a new question and include the code and the error traceback (if you can't figure it out yourself).